# Given regex does not match to the end

Tags: python, regex, oniguruma

I have a regex expression:

```
^([ \t\r]*\S+){2}$
```

It matches `name` and  group matches `e`, in `name`.

I expected to not to match `name`, but `name name`; such as I wanted `\S+` work till it matches. I can make it work just a bit changing it:

```
^([ \t\r]*\S+)([ \t\r]+\S+)$
```

but I hoped it would be possible to make it shorter.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which language are you using?

Comment: @DennisMeng it's Oniguruma syntax in Python(regex in Sublime Text)

Comment: In that case, it might help to also tag this as python.

Comment: Thanks to everyone; unfortunately, I can accept only one answer, but I'd like to accept few. So, I accepted first one, which gave me what I wanted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+`, `*`, and `?` are not [possessive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html). They will match as much as they can *if that produces a valid match*, but if not, the regex engine will backtrack and try matching less. I don't think Python supports possessive quantifiers; you'll have to recode your regex if you don't want to match `name`.

Comment: Thank you. Such as my regex syntax is Oniguruma, it has possessive operators. My final code is `^([ \\t\\r]*\\S++){2}$`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the global modifier. I'm not sure which programming language you are using, but the syntax often resembles the following:

```
/$myregex/g
```

For example, given the following text:

> Hello Adam, how are you? Hello Sarah, how are you?

The regular expression `/Hello\s(.*),/g` will match both **Adam** and **Sarah**.

Comment: unfortunately, I'm using Oniguruma syntax, and I do not have `g` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

With your original expression, `^([ \t\r]*\S+){2}$`, `na` and `me` are matched separately as different groups since you do not force (due to the `*` in `[ \t\r]*`) a space character after the first group.

You can use a lookahead assertion:

```
^([ \t\r]*\S+(?!\S)){2}$
```

Or you can use alternation:

```
((^|\s+)\S+){2}$
```

Comment: thanks for the response, second example works the same way as my second example, but I hoped there's an easier way of doing it. First example works only if both words are equal, sorry for confusion.